# Lisp: Why does (- 1e16 1) yield 10000000000000000 not 9999999999999999?

Tags: floating-point, scheme, lisp

Or rather, why does `(= 1e16 (- 1e16 1))` return true? How can I receive more accurate answer?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1e16` is, in Scheme terms, an inexact number (or in more practical terms, a floating-point number). For (double-precision) floating point numbers above 2<sup>53</sup> (9007199254740992), the [ulp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) is greater than 1, which means changes by 1 are too small to be represented.<sup>†</sup>

10000000000000000, on the other hand, is an integer. If you do `(- 10000000000000000 1)`, you will indeed get back 999999999999999. In Scheme, you can also write `#e1e16` to represent the same quantity; the `#e` prefix makes the number exact (in Scheme terms; in practical terms, it means either an integer or rational).

† Try evaluating `(+ 9007199254740992.0 1)` and `(- 9007199254740992.0 1)`, then try evaluating `(+ 9007199254740992 1)` and `(- 9007199254740992 1)` for contrast with integers.